# Are there problems with this 'Soft Delete' solution using EAV tables?

Tags: sql, database-design, delete-row

I've read some information about the ugly side of just setting a `deleted_at` field in your tables to signify a row has been deleted.

Namely
http://richarddingwall.name/2009/11/20/the-trouble-with-soft-delete/

Are there any potential problems with taking a row from a table you want to delete and pivoting it into some EAV tables?

For instance.

Lets Say I have two tables `deleted` and `deleted_row` respectively described as follows.

```
    mysql> describe deleted;
    +------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
    +------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | 
    | tablename  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
    | deleted_at | timestamp    | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
    +------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

    mysql> describe deleted_rows;
    +--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | Field  | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
    +--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | id     | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | 
    | entity | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                | 
    | name   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
    | value  | blob         | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
    +--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Now when you wanted to delete a row from any table you would delete it from the table then insert it into these tables as such.

```
    deleted
    +----+-----------+---------------------+
    | id | tablename | deleted_at          |
    +----+-----------+---------------------+
    |  1 | products  | 2011-03-23 00:00:00 | 
    +----+-----------+---------------------+

    deleted_row
    +----+--------+-------------+-------------------------------+
    | id | entity | name        | value                         |
    +----+--------+-------------+-------------------------------+
    |  1 |      1 | Title       | A Great Product               | 
    |  2 |      1 | Price       | 55.00                         | 
    |  3 |      1 | Description | You guessed it... it's great. | 
    +----+--------+-------------+-------------------------------+
```

A few things I see off the bat.

1. You'll need to use application logic
   to do the pivot (Ruby, PHP, Python,
   etc)
2. The table could grow pretty big
   because I'm using `blob` to handle
   the unknown size of the row value

**Do you see any other glaring problems with this type of soft delete?**

Comment: I don't have much of an opinion on whether it is a good thing or not (at least not without a lot more details about your requirements) but depending on your database server you can probably do this with triggers and keep the logic out of the database.

Comment: Tom, I haven't stumbled on how to do a pivot with triggers, do you know of any good examples online?

Comment: Sorry, not off the top of my head.  It also very much depends on what db you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not mirror your tables with archive tables?

```
create table mytable(
   col_1 int
  ,col_2 varchar(100)
  ,col_3 date 
  ,primary key(col_1)
)

create table mytable_deleted(
   delete_id  int      not null auto_increment
  ,delete_dtm datetime not null
-- All of the original columns
  ,col_1 int
  ,col_2 varchar(100)
  ,col_3 date 
  ,index(col_1)
  ,primary key(delete_id)
)
```

And then simply add on-delete-triggers on your tables that inserts the current row in the mirrored table before the deletion? That would provide you with dead-simple and very performant solution.

You could actually generate the tables and trigger code using the data dictionary.

Note that I might not want to have a unique index on the original primary key (col_1) in the archive table, because you may actually end up deleting the same row twice over time if you are using natural keys. Unless you plan to hook up the archive tables in your application (for undo purposes) you can drop the index entirely. Also, I added the time of delete (deleted_dtm) and a surrogate key that can be used to delete the deleted (hehe) rows.

You may also consider range partitioning the archive table on deleted_dtm. This makes it pretty much effortless to purge data from the tables.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid manually creating tables, but I can see the merit in this approach as it would not need any application logic.

Comment: @nvoyageur, what database are you using? Are you familiar with the dictionary tables of that dbms? You can create a set of procedures or scripts that enables/disables the archiving functionality, so you won't have to manually create the tables. And yes, the ability to have the database do this automatically in the background with out custom application code is very powerful!

Comment: MySQL is the primary DB I use (with a few projects in Postgres). I have not had any experience with dictionary tables. Something for me to look into.

Comment: @nvoy, Google for "information_schema", and have a look at the tables in the schema with the same name in your database.

Comment: @nvoy, did it work out for you? Don't forget to vote and/or accept if you find the answer useful to your problem.